# There already exists an object in the database SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have created a stored procedure that returns the id of last inserted row of a table based on one condition.

Condition is such that if the row being inserted already exists then it takes identity column of the row otherwise it inserts a new row into the table.

To do this, I have written the following code in a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_Procedure] 
    @description nvarchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempId int;

    SELECT CommentId 
    INTO tempId 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE description = @description;

    IF @tempId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TestTable 
        VALUES (@description);

        SELECT scope_identity();
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @tempId FROM dual;
    END

    DROP TABLE tempId;
END
```

When I run the above stored procedure, first time it ran successfully and then on wards it started throwing the following error message

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Procedure Test_Procedure, Line 15
>   There is already an object named 'tempId' in the database.

The bit I'm not understanding is `tempId` is used as a variable not as a table. I have seen people with the similar problem but in their case they used temporary tables

I really appreciate your help in resolving the above issue.

Comment: That is because the first time you run it the table tempId does not exist. But the next time you run it, that table has already been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax for setting your variable.

```
SELECT @tempId  = CommentId from TestTable where description = @description;
```

Currently your 'select into' is creating a table 'tempId' on the database.